# SOAP > Uncaught SoapFault exception: [HTTP] SoapClient->__doRequest

Tags: php, soap, google-dfp

Anyone shed light on why I'm getting this error?  I'm guessing it's because some of the paths in the WSDL don't resolve?

Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [HTTP] Could not connect to host in /usr/local/ampps/www/dfpapi/googleads-php-lib/src/Google/AdsApi/Common/AdsSoapClient.php:90 Stack trace: #0 /usr/local/ampps/www/dfpapi/googleads-php-lib/src/Google/AdsApi/Common/AdsSoapClient.php(90): SoapClient->__doRequest('https://ads.goo...', '', 1, 0) #1 [internal function]: Google\AdsApi\Common\AdsSoapClient->__doRequest('https://ads.goo...', '', 1, 0) #2 /usr/local/ampps/www/dfpapi/googleads-php-lib/src/Google/AdsApi/Common/AdsSoapClient.php(131): SoapClient->__soapCall('getCurrentNetwo...', Array, NULL, Array, Array) #3 /usr/local/ampps/www/dfpapi/googleads-php-lib/src/Google/AdsApi/Dfp/v201711/NetworkService.php(98): Google\AdsApi\Common\AdsSoapClient->__soapCall('getCurrentNetwo...', Array) #4 /usr/local/ampps/www/dfpapi/googleads-php-lib/getdfpdata.php(36): Google\AdsApi\Dfp\v201711\NetworkService->getCurrentNetwork() #5 /usr/local/ampps/www/dfpapi/googleads-php-lib/getdfpdata.php(96): Run in /usr/local/ampps/www/dfpapi/googleads-php-lib/src/Google/AdsApi/Common/AdsSoapClient.php on line 90

My code is

```
require 'vendor/autoload.php';
use Google\AdsApi\Common\OAuth2TokenBuilder;
use Google\AdsApi\Dfp\DfpServices;
use Google\AdsApi\Dfp\DfpSession;
use Google\AdsApi\Dfp\DfpSessionBuilder;
use Google\AdsApi\Dfp\Util\v201711\ReportDownloader;
use Google\AdsApi\Dfp\Util\v201711\StatementBuilder;
use Google\AdsApi\Dfp\v201711\Column;
use Google\AdsApi\Dfp\v201711\DateRangeType;
use Google\AdsApi\Dfp\v201711\Dimension;
use Google\AdsApi\Dfp\v201711\ExportFormat;
use Google\AdsApi\Dfp\v201711\NetworkService;
use Google\AdsApi\Dfp\v201711\ReportJob;
use Google\AdsApi\Dfp\v201711\ReportQuery;
use Google\AdsApi\Dfp\v201711\ReportQueryAdUnitView;
use Google\AdsApi\Dfp\v201711\ReportService;

/**
 * This example runs a typical daily inventory report and saves it in your
 * system's temp directory. It filters on the network's root ad unit ID. This is
 * only to demonstrate filtering for the purposes of this example, as filtering
 * on the root ad unit is equivalent to not filtering on any ad units.
 */
class RunInventoryReport {

  public static function runExample(DfpServices $dfpServices,
      DfpSession $session) {
    $reportService = $dfpServices->get($session, ReportService::class);
    $networkService = $dfpServices->get($session, NetworkService::class);

    // Get the network's root ad unit ID to filter on.
    $rootAdUnitId =
        $networkService->getCurrentNetwork()->getEffectiveRootAdUnitId();

    // Create statement to filter on a parent ad unit with the root ad unit ID
    // to include all ad units in the network.
    $statementBuilder = (new StatementBuilder())
        ->where('PARENT_AD_UNIT_ID = :parentAdUnitId')
        ->withBindVariableValue('parentAdUnitId', intval($rootAdUnitId));

    // Create report query.
    $reportQuery = new ReportQuery();
    $reportQuery->setDimensions([
        Dimension::AD_UNIT_ID,
        Dimension::AD_UNIT_NAME
    ]);
    $reportQuery->setColumns([
        Column::AD_SERVER_IMPRESSIONS,
        Column::AD_SERVER_CLICKS,
        Column::DYNAMIC_ALLOCATION_INVENTORY_LEVEL_IMPRESSIONS,
        Column::DYNAMIC_ALLOCATION_INVENTORY_LEVEL_CLICKS,
        Column::TOTAL_INVENTORY_LEVEL_IMPRESSIONS,
        Column::TOTAL_INVENTORY_LEVEL_CPM_AND_CPC_REVENUE
    ]);
    // Set the filter statement.
    $reportQuery->setStatement($statementBuilder->toStatement());
    // Set the ad unit view to hierarchical.
    $reportQuery->setAdUnitView(ReportQueryAdUnitView::HIERARCHICAL);
    // Set the start and end dates or choose a dynamic date range type.
    $reportQuery->setDateRangeType(DateRangeType::YESTERDAY);

    // Create report job and start it.
    $reportJob = new ReportJob();
    $reportJob->setReportQuery($reportQuery);
    $reportJob = $reportService->runReportJob($reportJob);

    // Create report downloader to poll report's status and download when ready.
    $reportDownloader =
        new ReportDownloader($reportService, $reportJob->getId());
    if ($reportDownloader->waitForReportToFinish()) {
      // Write to system temp directory by default.
      $filePath = sprintf(
          '%s.csv.gz',
          tempnam(sys_get_temp_dir(), 'inventory-report-')
      );
      printf("Downloading report to %s ...\n", $filePath);
      // Download the report.
      $reportDownloader->downloadReport(ExportFormat::CSV_DUMP, $filePath);
      print "done.\n";
    } else {
      print "Report failed.\n";
    }
  }

  public static function main() {
    $oAuth2Credential = (new OAuth2TokenBuilder())
        ->fromFile('src/Google/AdsApi/Common/Testing/adsapi_php.ini')
        ->build();
    $session = (new DfpSessionBuilder())
        ->fromFile('src/Google/AdsApi/Common/Testing/adsapi_php.ini')
        ->withOAuth2Credential($oAuth2Credential)
        ->build();
    self::runExample(new DfpServices(), $session);
  }
}

RunInventoryReport::main();
```

I'm using Googleads lib API version :v201711

Please help me to solve this

Comment: read your exception : `Could not connect to host ...` maybe some code sample will help to indentify your problem

Comment: can you show your php code?

Comment: Ben -  Please check the code.